# Using existing “Date” variable; add month and week variables to the data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, lubridate

I have a data frame called Covid19 and it contains a variable called Date. I want to create two new variables Month and Week from the Date variable. [The output must look as in the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/by1qV.png)
The code I wrote is :

```
Covid19_df <- Covid19_df$Date %>% mutate(Month = lubridate::month(date), 
                Week = lubridate::week(date))
```

but it gives an error

```
Error in UseMethod("mutate_") : 
  no applicable method for 'mutate_' applied to an object of class "Date"
```

Can anyone give me a possible solution or new code get the desired output.

Comment: `Covid19_df <- Covid19_df %>% mutate(Month = lubridate::month(Date), 
                Week = lubridate::week(Date))`

Comment: Names are case sensitive, as demonstrated by Ronak.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax that you were looking for is :

```
library(dplyr)

Covid19_df <- Covid19_df %>% 
                mutate(Month = lubridate::month(Date), 
                        Week = lubridate::week(Date))
```